# Shnayim Ve'esrim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twenty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Rashi, Rivka died at 122. ([Citation.](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/salt-bereishit/06-10toledot.htm))

Answer (score 1):

[Yisachar son of Yaakov Avinu lived for 122 years](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=9757&st=%u05d9%u05e9%u05e9%u05db%u05e8) Yalkut Shimoni - Shemos

Answer (score 0):

Both Parshas Vayakheil and Parshas Ki Sovo have 122 Pesukim